# Missing build.scala in base directory

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I am trying my hands on the sbt version 12
with the tutorials from GitHub.
I installed the sbt from sbt windows installer package 
but any time I run sbt, the project runs but 
i cannot find the build.scala file in the base directory
rather i find a target folder in the base directory with the scala file

below is the simple scala code from github

```
object Hi {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = println("Hi!")
}
```

the code is defined in a scala file.
even though the code runs but i cannot find the build.scala file. 
the point is that I want to build an akka project and i believe i will have to add some configurations in the build.cala file

any idea please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SBT uses the so called "convention over configuration" approach. This means that for a simple project no configuration is required. So if you want to configure your project use either the light configuration (just create a `build.sbt` file in the `root` directory of your project) or the full configuration (just create a `build.scala` file in the `root/project` directory of your project). Consult the "Using Akka with SBT" section at the [Akka's documentation website](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/intro/getting-started.html) for akka dependencies and [this site](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Basic-Def) for the SBT configuration. Note that there is also an excellent guide for SBT available at the [SBT's website](http://www.scala-sbt.org/howto.html).

Answer (score 1):

The build.scala file goes into your /project directory which you should create in the project root folder. Read [this page](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Full-Def) of the documentation.

With regard to Akka, I would start with a [template project](http://typesafe.com/stack/download#template) referred to in the [getting started](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/intro/getting-started.html) documentation, rather than trying to build it from scratch.